# Unable to execute the WSO2 OB merge script inside WSO2 IS, getting permission denied?

Tags: permissions, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

```
Icp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/88/dbe33acc44c56db8cdd05f449ed90c7a30c4c5': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/89/8b56f1ce4093ef95f88d1a878870f38ef928d1': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/8b/4deef3cf9f3ae3308991bf475c148f1bd7c642': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/8b/680ca366e4b4ee5cdc83f801b8cd2783f8b5d6': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/8b/8507bf49a11770a599698f8cad96573928aa4c': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/8b/de389221af972270b635e2166e0362e7daa403': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e3/30ac594fe120971788519e372b916e3190d1a7': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e3/fd553cf55e781eb0b6e9ef94e3d4745d530112': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e4/e1d52c9e9952e1ae0edb088a8ad845bd2f115f': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e5/1d2b50ecdf8baf390e8f3808fe159d03700977': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e5/880a783b98a27870bef5a80b929586de08f214': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e8/95fadb3158676253a81f8dc60cc382c976e5b9': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e8/c24c0aae19f57c4d9d10adfb475be124f2cb0f': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e8/ffebf688e7615aefa84f030e5d6fe7c7909423': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e9/3adf86fa274cb44bc1ece390487ed8b45fcf27': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e9/42d70f5cd4fece5b76d4ac766641ba55e48a66': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/e9/c91a9b1aa7f0df401e722b0f8cdbf2bbc6fd86': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/ec/3c7af690348ec7b6293efbbd572b9cc0d6fad6': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/f/WSO2 OB Practice/BaseProducts/wso2is-5.11.0/WSO2/Desktop/HelthCare/.git/objects/ec/6d8754eb2341e92846fcd1be42471344a22a30': Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you tried giving permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know which version of OB you are trying to setup.

Please rename the `WSO2 OB Practice` folder to a name without spaces like `WSO2_OB_Practice` and provide executable permission to the merge script using the command `chmod +x <filename>.sh`